# Problem with casting in java for android

Tags: java, android, casting

i have EditText in my program

my code:

```
Double Hi;
private EditText MyHight;
MyHight   = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

i need to insert to Hi the value on MyHight

i try this:

```
MyHight.getText().toString();
Hi= (Double)MyHight;
```

but i got error on casting

how to fix it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with:

```
Hi = Double.valueOf(MyHight.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't cast an `EditText` to a `Double`.

You could, however, construct a new `Double` from the `String`:

```
Hi = new Double(MyHight.getText().toString());
```

or:

```
Hi = Double.valueOf(MyHight.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing something like:

```
Double Hi = Double.valueOf( (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1)).getText().toString())
```

I used to do the standard casting like the answer by Oli but got tired of handling errors and such.  So I wrote a whole class of Casting here is an example of what I did with doubles.

```
public class Cast {
/**
 *  Base number cast, return the value or default
 * @param object - generic Object
 * @param defaultValue - default value to give if Object is null
 * @return - returns type Number
 */
private static Number castImpl(Object object, Number defaultValue) {
    return (object!=null && object instanceof Number) ? (Number)object : defaultValue;
}


/**
 *  Base double cast, return the value or default
 * @param object - generic Object
 * @param defaultValue - default value to give if Object is null
 * @return - returns type double
 */
public static double cast(Object object, double defaultValue) { 
    return castImpl(object, defaultValue).doubleValue();
}
}
```

This will allow you use a default value too, here is how yo use it.

```
Cast.cast("3", 1.0);
```

I've even done this for Arrays too to convert from int to float arrays...